# How to populate a "select" form with flickr photoset titles? (with PHP)

Tags: php, json, photo, flickr

I'm in the process of creating a photo uploader that uploads photos directly to a personal flickr account... right now I'm trying to call all my photosets (by title) and populate my `select` dropdown with them. Unfortunately everything I've been trying hasn't worked... so I'm here for some help from you experienced people! ;)

Here's the code I'm working with:
From my file called `class.flickr.php`

```
// Code being used for the purpose of calling photoset titles
public function getPhotosets() {

    // Function specific variables
    $flickr_api_call        = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/";
    $method                 = "flickr.photosets.getList";
    $nsid                   = 'my user id';

    $url_parameters = array(
        'method'                =>$method,
        'oauth_consumer_key'    =>$this->flickr_key,
        'user_id'               =>$nsid,
        'format'                =>$this->format,
        'nojsoncallback'        =>'1',
        'oauth_nonce'           =>$this->nonce,
        'oauth_timestamp'       =>$this->timestamp,
        'oauth_version'         =>'1.0',    
    );

    $parameters_string = "";

    foreach ( $url_parameters as $key=>$value ) $parameters_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&";

    $url = $flickr_api_call . "?" . $parameters_string;

    $photosets = array();
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

    if ( $data['stat'] != 'fail' ) {

        $photosets = $data['photosets']['photoset'];
        return $photosets;
    } else {

        return false;
    }

    var_dump( $photosets );
} // end getPhotosets
```

The code being used to call the `getPhotosets` method within my main document:

```
<select class="categorize-options">

<?php 
    require_once( 'class.flickr.php' );

    $flickr = new Flickr( 'api key', 'api shared secret' );
    $results = $flickr->getPhotosets();

    if ( !empty( $results )):
        foreach( $results as $photoset ):?>

            <option><?php echo $photoset['title']; ?></option>

        <?php endforeach;
    else:

        echo "This isn't working!!! :)";
    endif; 
?>
</select>
```

The thing that is really confusing me is that both the `var_dump()` and the `else` statement are not displaying... but, neither is anything else. Would be a great help to get some experienced input... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, though flickr documentation says you don't need authorization for the method `flickr.photosets.getList`... it is wrong. You will need to run an authorization function something like this:

```
// Get list of photosets (for their titles)
public function getPhotosets() {

    // Function specific variables
    $flickr_api_call        = $this->flickr_rest_call;
    $method                 = "flickr.photosets.getList";
    $nsid                   = 'user_id';
    $access_token           = "access_token";
    $access_token_secret    = "access_token_secret";

    $url  = "format=" . $this->format;
    $url .= "&method=" . $method;
    $url .= "&nojsoncallback=1";
    $url .= "&oauth_consumer_key=" . $this->flickr_key;
    $url .= "&oauth_nonce=" . $this->nonce;
    $url .= "&oauth_signature_method=" . $this->sig_method;
    $url .= "&oauth_timestamp=" . $this->timestamp;
    $url .= "&oauth_token=" . $access_token;
    $url .= "&oauth_version=1.0";
    $url .= "&user_id=" . urlencode( $nsid );

    $baseurl            = "GET&" . urlencode( $flickr_api_call ) . "&" . urlencode( $url );
    $hashkey            = $this->flickr_secret . "&" . $access_token_secret;
    $oauth_signature    = base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $baseurl, $hashkey, true ));

    $url_parameters = array(
        'method'                =>$method,
        'oauth_consumer_key'    =>$this->flickr_key,
        'user_id'               =>$nsid,
        'format'                =>$this->format,
        'nojsoncallback'        =>'1',
        'oauth_nonce'           =>$this->nonce,
        'oauth_timestamp'       =>$this->timestamp,
        'oauth_signature_method'=>$this->sig_method,
        'oauth_version'         =>'1.0',
        'oauth_token'           =>$access_token,
        'oauth_signature'       =>$oauth_signature
    );

    /* Now that we have encoded the parameters for our ouath_signature
    * and have reformated them for the url we need to send... we must
    * re-urlencode them too. */

    $parameters_string = "";
    foreach ( $url_parameters as $key=>$value )
        $parameters_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&";

    $url = $flickr_api_call . "?" . $parameters_string;
```

NOTE: any time you use `nsid` you need to `urlencode` the value twice! Reason: the `@`, if only encoded once will return like this `%40`, but in order to keep the `%` you MUST encode twice resulting in this: `%2540`

Secondly, change your call from the json response from this: `<option><?php echo $photoset['title']; ?></option>` to this: `<option><?php echo $photoset['title']['_content']; ?></option>`

This is how I was able to accomplish this... if there is a better, more efficient way of doing this I'd love to hear about it.